# How to get data from custom adapter in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter

here is my problem :

I created a custom adapter for my ListView and I get information out of a List that I give to that adapter in order to let him fulfill my ListView. He does everything correctly. Now I'd like to implement an **OnItemClickListener** and to get the data from it. But in that list I have 4 TextViews ...

***How can I retrieve the data*** ?

I already know how to get the id and position since I display them in a Toast.

**Thanks a lot for your help !**

Here is the custom Adapter :

```
public class NextRdvAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NextRdv> {
private List<NextRdv> listNextRdv = new ArrayList<NextRdv>(); 
private Context context; 

public NextRdvAdapter(List<NextRdv> nextRdvList, Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.list_next_rdv, nextRdvList);
    this.listNextRdv = nextRdvList; 
    this.context = ctx;
} 

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) { // This a new view we inflate the new layout 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_next_rdv, parent, false); 
        } // Now we can fill the layout with the right values 

    TextView tvTimeStart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.next_time_start); 
    TextView tvTimeEnd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.next_time_end); 
    TextView tvEnterprise = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.next_enterprise_name); 
    TextView tvAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.next_address); 
    NextRdv rdv = listNextRdv.get(position); 

    tvTimeStart.setText(rdv.getStartTime());
    tvTimeEnd.setText(rdv.getEndTime());
    tvEnterprise.setText(rdv.getEnterprise());
    tvAddress.setText(rdv.getAddress());


    return convertView; 
    }
}
```

Here is my Fragment that posess the ListView :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{

float density;

//Everything you need about this rdv
private ListView lvThisRdv;
private List<NextRdv> listThisRdv = new ArrayList<NextRdv>();
private NextRdvAdapter ThisRdvAdapter;  
private NextRdvListBouchon thisBouchon;

//Everything you need about next rdv
private ListView lvNextRdv;
private List<NextRdv> listNextRdv = new ArrayList<NextRdv>();
private NextRdvAdapter nextRdvAdapter;  
private NextRdvListBouchon bouchon;

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    lvThisRdv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_this_RDV);
    thisBouchon = new NextRdvListBouchon();
    listThisRdv = thisBouchon.getBouchonInc();
    ThisRdvAdapter = new NextRdvAdapter(listThisRdv, getActivity());
    lvThisRdv.setAdapter(ThisRdvAdapter);

    //Displaying the list of the next meetings
    lvNextRdv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_next_RDV);

    //Get test data
    bouchon = new NextRdvListBouchon();
    listNextRdv = bouchon.getBouchon();

    nextRdvAdapter = new NextRdvAdapter(listNextRdv, getActivity());
    lvNextRdv.setAdapter(nextRdvAdapter);

    lvNextRdv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

              //
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pos : " +position+ " / id : " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
              toast.show();
          }

    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

inside `onItemClick` you can use the `AdapterView` argument,

```
NextRdv item = (NextRdv) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Comment: Okay I'll try that, thanks for that amazing answer's speed !!

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks again for both your pace and precision !

Comment: So this means that the adapter will not only fetch the data but also keep the items in the list ? Do you have any link or any topic that would explain this point that I could read ?

Comment: Sorry can you rephrase?

Comment: When I look at my ListView I can see 4 TextViews but it's possible that I retrieve the object that I used to populate this LV before. 
So I suppose that the associated object is still here, linked somewhere to the position of my LV, it's not only read and destroyed, it's now part of the LV, do you know how to call this fact or do you have a link I could read for detailed explainations of what happen when I LV.setAdapter(myAdapter); ?

Comment: Dataset is strictly bounded to the adapter which in turn is strictly bounded with the ListView. Nothing is destroyed. Views are recycled but they are unrelated to the dataset

Comment: Thanks for that vocab, I'm going to study that point further. Wish you a great day !

Answer (score 7):

You can use below code

```
 lvNextRdv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

       // selected item
       String selected =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.your_textView_item_id)).getText().toString();

        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

      }

});
```

using this u can get the data of any TextView inside custom adapter for selected row.

Hope will help you...

Comment: blackbelts answer is better. you have to initialize the view again

Comment: Yes that is also another way to do this

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Blackbelts already provided me with one that seems more convenient to me. Thanks for the help though !